# InfluxDB design issue

Tags: influxdb, nosql

I am using influxDB and using line protocol to insert large set of data into Data base. Data i am getting is in the form of Key value pair, where key is long string contains Hierarchical data and value is simple integer value.

Sample Key Value data :

```
/path/units/unit/subunits/subunit[name\='NAME1']/memory/chip/application/filter/allocations
value = 500

/path/units/unit/subunits/subunit[name\='NAME2']/memory/chip/application/filter/allocations
value = 100
(Note Name = 2)

/path/units/unit/subunits/subunit[name\='NAME1']/memory/chip/application/filter/free
value = 700
(Note Instead of allocation it is free at the leaf)

/path/units/unit/subunits/subunit[name\='NAME2']/memory/graphics/application/filter/swap
value = 600
Note Instead of chip, graphics is in path)

/path/units/unit/subunits/subunit[name\='NAME2']/harddisk/data/size
value = 400
Note Different path but till subunit it is same

/path/units/unit/subunits/subunit[name\='NAME2']/harddisk/data/free
value=100
Note Same path but last element is different
```

Below is the line protocol i am using to insert data.

```
interface, Key= /path/units/unit/subunits/subunit[name\='NAME2']/harddisk/data/free, valueData= 500
```

I am Using one measurement namely, Interface. And one tag and one field set. But this DB design is causing issue for querying data.

How can I design database so that i can query like, Get all record for subunit where name = Name1 or get all size data for every hard disk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about whats going on here. Can you give me the example query that you'd like to run.

Comment: @MichaelDesa I am wondering about schema design for efficient retrieval of above mention data: for e.g. /path/units/unit/subunits/subunit[name\='NAME2']/harddisk/data/free  or /path/units/unit/subunits/subunit[name\='NAME2']/harddisk/data/allocation

Comment: Whats the cardinality of the `Key` value?

Comment: It is one to many. Value is simple integer data and can be save in a column. Only thing i am worried about how to efficiently save Key data. For Key you can consider it as PATH data. for e.g. like out put of pwd command.

Comment: How many different values can it have though? 1000? 1000000? Infinite?

Comment: It could be around in range of 1000 to 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Schema I'd recommend would be the following:

```
interface,filename=/path/units/unit/subunits/subunit[name\='NAME2']/harddisk/data/free value=500
```

Where `filename` is a tag and `value` is the field.

Given that the cardinality of `filename` in the thousands this schema should work well.

Comment: Thanks Michael, how can i query on substring part of keys? for e.g. Get count of 'value' for all of the "/harddisk"  having name = "NAME2"

Comment: InfluxQL supports regular expressions on tags so your query would look something like this `SELECT * FROM interface WHERE filename =~ /harddisk/`. Though if you're doing a lot of queries that have regular expression matches, I would probably recommend splitting `filename` into multiple tags.